# Copy/paste from vbox to windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am using Windows 10 and VBox v5.1.6r110634 (Qt5.5.1). Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and GNOME Terminal 3.18.3.

I am trying to copy from a Ubuntu system to my Windows 10 Visual Studio v14.0.25431.01 Update 3. I have set Ubuntu's settings to be bidirectional just as described on a web page (Settings->General->Advanced->Shared Clipboard and Drag'n'Drop to Bidirectional). But the copy/paste from a terminal to Windows does not work. I have verified that the Copy operation in Ubuntu works because I can then Past to Ubuntu. But when I try to Paste to Visual Studio it does not work. I have tried a complete shutdown of Vbox and restarted it but still no help. I have checked to be sure I have the guest additions loaded so that is not the problem.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be going on?

Comment: Why did you mark this down? If you don't know the answer then please don't respond.

Comment: I have seen this problem too. I have seen it work but sometimes it doesn't work and I have never found the answer.

Comment: I figured out copy/paste problem below way. This might help you. [Enable copying and pasting text between an Ubuntu 16.04.2 guest running in Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.14 running on a Windows 7 host and the Windows 7 host](https://www.zachpfeffer.com/single-post/2017/02/18/Enabling-copying-and-pasting-text-between-an-Ubuntu-16042-guest-running-in-Oracle-VM-VirtualBox-5114-running-on-Windows-7-and-the-Windows-7-host)

Answer (score 0):

Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image -> Install -> Restart.
Remember activate bi-directional shared clipboard!

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to install some libraries if its from a standard Ubuntu desktop build

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-ext-pack
```

And Install Insert Additions CD Image from the device menu of the virtualbox window of the running VM.

Answer (score 0):

**How to enable bi-directional copy and paste on virtual box/ubuntu 16.4**

pkill 'VBoxClient --clipboard' -f & sleep 1 && VBoxClient --clipboard

I ran this command on virtualbox(5.2)/ubuntu(16.4). It worked for me. I have enabled the bi-direction mode in settings->advance as well and after that ran this command.
Finally, trying so many methods, this one worked for me.